HP Laserjet M283fdw stopped talking to Windows/HP Smart
I have an HP LaserJet MFP283fdw with non-HP toner. I turned off automatic firmware updates a long time ago to make sure HP couldn't stop me using non-HP toner.
But recently my Windows 10 PC has stopped even being able to see the printer, calling it Offline. Same on my phone with HP Smart. Nothing has changed on my printer and my Linux PC (not using HP-supplied drivers) can see and print to it fine, just as always.
It seems possible to me that newer HP driver software will now silently ignore any printer without the current firmware, in order to force people onto newer firmware that forces HP products. Can anyone confirm if that's what is going on here? However if I update the printer firmware, presumably it will start to reject my 3rd party toner, right?
Anyone using an M283fdw with non-HP toner successfully?

@John have you left automatic firmware updates turned on? There is lots of commentary online about recent (ish) firmware updates preventing non-HP toner from working, eg https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Setup-Software-Drivers/Problem-with-new-firmware-and-HP-orginal-toners/td-p/8880902

@John OK, so do you have an alternative source of firmware? (that works with the latest / standard HP drivers / HP Smart app??)

There are various older HP drivers onlinwe, such as at https://printerdrivers.com/hp-color-laserjet-pro-mfp-m283fdw-driver/. Before installing any software, check at https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload .

How's it connected? If its network, its possible the windows box and phone are looking at the wrong IP and the linux box isn't. Maybe try running the driver software/setup again?

Have you tried to uninstall HP Smart and install one of the older drivers mentioned in a comment above?

@DrMoishePippik Thanks for the response. I tried uninstalling the installed HP Smart and installing drivers from that page. Unfortunately there has been no change in behaviour - the printer is never detected, not even if I explicitly give it the IP address (which I verified).

@JourneymanGeek Sadly, I have already verified the IP address is the same in all cases. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling drivers with no change in behaviour.

@1NN Yes I have tried that now, but unfortunately it hasn't helped.

Have you tried to remove the printer, then use the 'add new printer' dialogue ?

@1NN - yes I have, many times, without success :(

I think it may be as you fear, that original HP drivers can block your old firmware. HP will not confirm it. This is easy to prove when your linux printing does work.
I personally would try PrintFab as that is good alternative for the drivers from HP and ditch HP drivers altogether.
It seems that your printer is not at the list of supported printers, but from my experience with TurboPrint for linux the developer(s) reacts quite quickly if you ask him for support for your printer.
Edit:
You can ask about your printer directly via the Feedback on PrintFab / Windows

Thank you for this suggestion, it's the most helpful I've had!

@Vicky you are welcome.  Please let us know if this will help you in the end.  I will update the answer with your information.
